# Closing the commutative diagram for symplectic realizations

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, poisson-geometry

Let $f: (M_1, P_1) \to (M_2, P_2)$ be a Poisson map between Poisson manifolds. Let $\pi_i : (S_i, \omega_i) \to (M_i, P_i), \ i=1,2$ be symplectic realizations. Putting these objects in a rectangular diagram, there is a "missing" edge between $S_1$ and $S_2$, which forms the content of my question: is there *any* meaningful way of closing this diagram (and making it commutative) with symplectic or Poisson maps?

I don't expect to find a map between $S_1$ and $S_2$, this seems impossible to happen in general. I wonder, though, whether such a map might exist *locally*: given $x_2 = f(x_1)$ and $y_i \in \pi_i ^{-1} (x_i)$, is it possible to find open sets $U_i \ni y_i$ and some $g : U_1 \to U_2$ (with what properties?) such that $g(y_1) = y_2$ and $\pi_2 \circ g = f \circ \pi_1 \big| _{U_1}$?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking at symplectic groupoids you may well look at their infinitesimal version, Lie algebroids, and ask yourself if a Poisson map lifts to a Lie algebroid map. This is not the case (or, to be precise, this is possible only if the map is a Poisson diffeomorphism). You can see this by considering that, in a way, given a Poisson map from $M_1$ to $M_2$ you do not have, in general, a naturally defined map from $T^*M_1$ (global space of the Lie algebroid of $M_1$) to $T^* M_2$.

There is an interesting recent  paper on considering a different notion, that of Lie algebroid comorphism, as a suitable lift of Poisson maps:

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.4443.pdf

Comment: Your argument about natural maps from $T^* M_1$ to $T^* M_2$ is precisely what I had in mind. Nevertheless, if $S_1$ and $S_2$ are open subsets of $T^* M_1$ and $T^* M_2$ like in the construction of symplectic realizations by [Crainic and Mărcuţ](http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.2085), then it is natural to contemplate the map $T^* M_1 \ni \eta \mapsto \textrm d f (\eta ^\sharp) ^\flat \in T^* M_2$ (where the musical isomorphisms are given by the corresponding symplectic forms).